# Http request header "Accept-Charset" is not recognized

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, jetty, google-chrome-app

I am trying to make a REST call using chrome DHC and Advanced rest clients. For example:

A HEAD call to http://www.google.co.in
 using advanced REST client gives:

```
Redirect To:https://www.google.co.in/ with status: 302 Show explanation HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Redirection information has not been cached.
Location: https://www.google.co.in/ 
Cache-Control: private 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 06:57:46 GMT 
Server: gws 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic
Content-Length: 222 
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Status
200 OK Show explanation Loading time: 764


Request headers 
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
X-Chrome-Variations: <some value>
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Cookie: <some value>

Response headers 
status: 200 OK
version: HTTP/1.1
alternate-protocol: 443:quic
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 34821
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 29 Nov 2013 06:57:46 GMT
expires: -1
server: gws
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

I am more interested on details of request header as **"Accept-Charset"** is not recognized. If i give anything as header it is atleast displayed in request header. Now some questions:

1. why this is not recognized? is this client problem or server problem? do i need to use any other client. I am not aware.
2. If it is recognized then I should be able to validate this value in server code, which in my case is running in jetty?

Thanks,
Akhi

Answer (score 0):

I found that its a client problem, specific to Chrome. I dont know why with chrome this header is completely ignored. 
When i tried to send http request using **CURL** command, i was able to retrieve this header. Now i can go ahead with validation of "Accept-Charset" header.